# Avoid Duplicates Record

Tags: mysql, join

```
SELECT DISTINCT log.employee,
log.attendance_date ,

case when ch.log_type = 'IN' then TIME_FORMAT(ch.time,"%H:%i:%s") end as attend_time ,      
case   WHEN  ch.log_type = 'IN' THEN CONCAT(MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(ch.shift_start , ch.time)),24), ':',
                        MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(ch.shift_start , ch.time))) 
                        END as late_in
                        
                
from `tabAttendance`  log 
left outer join `tabEmployee Checkin` ch 
on (log.employee = ch.employee and log.attendance_date = DATE_FORMAT(ch.time,"%Y-%m-%d"))
                
ORDER by log.employee ASC , log.attendance_date asc
```

My Result is :

[image]

Comment: Please look at [mcve] for how to construct a good question.

Comment: FYI, each row in your output *is* unique.

Comment: What is the _desired_ result?